# ReactJs object literal function updates entire state and not the intended

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have a simple font awesome stars for rating. Only the star that's clicked should turn orange and the rest should not. The class for the orange star depends on the state. Code below

```
   import React, {useState} from 'react';
   import './rating.css';

function Rating() {

  const [state, setState] = useState({first:false, second:false, third:false, fourth:false, 
                                     fifth:false});

    const rate = (index) => {
        console.log(index)
        return{
            '1': setState(prevState=>({...prevState, first: !state.first })),
            '2': setState(prevState=>({...prevState, second: !state.second })),
            '3': setState(prevState=>({...prevState, third: !state.third })),
            '4': setState(prevState=>({...prevState, fourth: !state.fourth })),
            '5': setState(prevState=>({...prevState, fifth: !state.fifth }))
        }[index]
    };

    return (
        <div className="rating">
            <span className={`fa fa-star ${state.first ? "checked" : ""}`} onClick={()=>rate('1')}></span>
            <span className={`fa fa-star ${state.second ? "checked" : ""}`} onClick={()=>rate('2')}></span>
            <span className={`fa fa-star ${state.third ? "checked" : ""}`} onClick={()=>rate('3')}></span>
            <span className={`fa fa-star ${state.fourth ? "checked" : ""}`} onClick={()=>rate('4')}></span>
            <span className={`fa fa-star ${state.fifth ? "checked" : ""}`} onClick={()=>rate('5')}></span>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Rating;
```

The issue is when I click on a star, all the stars turn yellow. The index in the rate function is expected to decide which star's state gets toggled.  Console logged...The index is coming correct in rate function. I tried without prevState/callback and an anonymous function like below. Nothing helped. **What is going wrong here?**

```
'1': ()=>setState(prevState=>({...prevState, first: !state.first }))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not quite sure what you expect the `rate` function to do.. It seems like you've created an object that is supposed to have a method for each index, and then you're attempting to call it by `[index]`? Not only is that way over-complicated, its also not setup right. You're calling `setState` on each method, not assigning a function (like `() => setState(...)`).

I would advise that you don't use this "index" system at all and just pass the value you want to update:

```js
const rate = (name) => {
  setState({ ...state, [name]: !state[name] });
};

...

// Example usage:
<span className={`fa fa-star ${state.first ? "checked" : ""}`} onClick={()=>rate('first')}></span>
```

If you're set on using the object style, try this (untested):

```js
const rate = (index) => {
  let actions = {
    '1': () => setState(prevState=>({...prevState, first: !prevState.first })),
    '2': () => setState(prevState=>({...prevState, second: !prevState.second })),
    '3': () => setState(prevState=>({...prevState, third: !prevState.third })),
    '4': () => setState(prevState=>({...prevState, fourth: !prevState.fourth })),
    '5': () => setState(prevState=>({...prevState, fifth: !prevState.fifth }))
  };

  actions[index]() // <-- call it with ()
};
```